# how create a box like this in css3

Tags: html, css

This is how I want it to be:

[image: ss]

Please check to this link and see the readmore image.
I want to look like this in css3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```css
.button{
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #89ae56 0%, #85a06d 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #89ae56 0%, #85a06d 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #89ae56 0%, #85a06d 100%);
    position:relative;  
    color:#fff;  
    line-height:30px; 
    padding-left:10px;   
}
.button:after{
    content:"+";
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:#5f5f5f;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    Read More
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways this could be achieved.  One would need to use a SPAN element, with a background gradient, rounded corners, white text with a text-shadow, something like this.

In your HTML:

```
<span class="button-span">Read More</span>
```

And in your CSS (background code generated at http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ for a pure-css gradient):

```
.button-span {  

    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

    /* Background gradient */
    background: #bfd255; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #bfd255 0%, #8eb92a 79%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#bfd255), color-   stop(79%,#8eb92a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #bfd255 0%,#8eb92a 79%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #bfd255 0%,#8eb92a 79%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #bfd255 0%,#8eb92a 79%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #bfd255 0%,#8eb92a 79%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bfd255', endColorstr='#8eb92a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Fiddle around with the values, if you want the little + icon too you could just use a transparent PNG with the symbol on it, or use a symbol from a font such as this one: http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ (You would need to find out how to embed fonts for this last option, but it's not too difficult)

Hope this helps!

Comment: but i want to totally css with plus icon and text shadow

Comment: @Rohitazad How far are you? Can you show what you've got now?